# Help with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have my site under the structure: `www.somesite.com/index.php?page=p_section_page.php`

I want my site to display something like: `www.somesite.com/section/page` OR just `www.somesite.com/page/`

Tried to write rules in the .htaccess file like so:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
 Options +Indexes  
 RewriteEngine On  
 RewriteBase /  
 RewriteRule PAGE index.php?page=p_section_page.php
```

It works fine if i try `www.somesite.com/page/` but the images, css files and js, try to access the `www.somesite.com/page/css/` or `www.somesite.com/images/` directories which clearly do not exist.

Any help here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My educated guess is that you are using relative paths. If you change the URL of the HTML document you change the effective path of pictures, scripts and other resources that are loaded via relative paths. It's the same as when you move the file to another directory.

I find it easier to call resources with absolute paths. You are using PHP so you have two options: hard-code the leading slash or use PHP to set it:

```
<img src="/images/picture.jpg" ... >
<img src="<?=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>images/picture.jpg" ... >
```

Comment: Talk about an educated answer :), I have completely overlooked that aspect. Thanks a million.